# IBM Worklight - How to enable App Authenticity in Worklight Console?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I tried to follow [the tutorial at this url](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/08_09_Application_Authenticity_Protection.pdf), the tutorial is so straight forward but I just couldn't get the correct outcome.

below is my authenticationConfig.xml

```
<securityTests>
  <customSecurityTest name="custom-mobilesecurityTest">
    <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
    <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="2"/>
    <test realm="HeaderAuthRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="3"/>
  </customSecurityTest>
</securityTests>
```

But the App Authentication appeared in console is always "Access Disabled", I can't enable it. Did I missing anything here?

[image]

Comment: what version of **Worklight** are you using **Developers edition or Consumer Edition or Enterprise Edition**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be more helpful if you would mention what you've actually done, because configuring `authenticationConfig.xml` is only 1 step of several.

Also note that for App Authenticity to **really work** and not use dummy implementation, you **must use** the Consumer edition of IBM Worklight (i.e., be a paying customer and install the correct version of Worklight Studio and Worklight Server).

*I believe that for your problem, you have not done step 2 below.*

**Steps to enable App Authenticity:**

1. Configure a security test that has the `wl_authenticityRealm` realm:

   > ```
   > <customSecurityTest name="customTests">
   >      <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
   >      <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
   >      <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
   >      <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
   >      <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
   > </customSecurityTest>
   > ```

   ^ This is mentioned in slide 9
2. Place this `securityTest` on the environment(s) in `application-descriptor.xml`, for example:

   > ```
   > <android version="1.0" securityTest="customTests">
   > ```
3. For Android, generate the public signing key:

   > ```
   > <android version="1.0" securityTest="customTests">
   >         <worklightSettings include="true"/>
   >         <security>
   >             <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
   >             <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
   >             <publicSigningKey>MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBdfdsfdsfiQKBgQCPCbaCfAfnAqQ12/S5LLfA4cBz/3INyLRPhFGSVFztdWNzPhrna1xDc8/3V1sUIW2odfdfddfdfffdR2n3dAnNMVydfdfdfv68gmU5qVCN4LxSKKRAj7VVbhBxBIEt5MbY+c0o7NZ2Pgu/moJee8Wgu8veZ1TJntYn+cWCYuI/JSnA9nsskwhSdPHK32edsfsdfdfQIDAQAB</publicSigningKey>
   >         </security>
   >     </android>
   > ```

   ^ This is mentioned in slides 10-13
4. For iOS, place the app `bundleId`:

   > `<iphone bundleId="com.worklight.test" version="1.0" securityTest="customTests">`

   ^ This is mentioned in slides 10-13
5. Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server

Now the App Authenticity dropdown should be enabled for you in Worklight Console.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the securityTest="customTests" in application-descriptor.xml wasn't really mentioned in the tutorial page. After applying your solution, it actually working in Eclipse > Run on Worklight Development Server, but it still doesn't show up in my WebSphere (Liberty Core ver.), any thought?

Comment: I have followed my instructions in a blank new app with the android and iPhone environments and it is working. Verify it works for you on s blank new app as well and then check what you've done wrong in your current app.

Comment: Yes Idan, I only redeploy the war but not the client in Websphere. Everything working properly now. Tq.

Comment: HI do I need to keep wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm for app authenticity in security test.

Comment: @IdanAdar does app authenticity works in Liberty Profile?

Comment: Yes. The feature is not related to the underlying application server. Note however that the feature is not supposed to work in the development environment (which is based on Liberty by chance, but not related to it not working in the development environment).