# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Controlling authenticity testing for an app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

How do I configure the worklight app to enable authenticity testing? 
I am unable to find exact step by step guide at IBM Worklight 6.1 Information Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic has a training module. You can find it in the [Authentication and Security](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/#security) section of IBM Worklight Getting Started, under "[Application Authenticity Protection](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08_09_Application_Authenticity_Protection.pdf)".

You may also want to look at this question: [IBM Worklight - How to enable App Authenticity in Worklight Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904497/ibm-worklight-how-to-enable-app-authenticity-in-worklight-console)

P.S.,
It's also in the Information Center:

- [IBM Worklight application authenticity overview](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_app_authentication_overview.html)
- [Controlling authenticity testing for an app](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/c_controlling_authenticity_testing.html)